# Time Calculation in PHP using MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a report to build in PHP where I need time difference times hourly rate for an employee pay.

For example:

```
Employee     Clock-In           Clock-Out     Total-Hours  Rate  Salary
Mike    2015-01-01 22:57:09 2015-01-02 11:48:14 12:51:05    10  128.51
Mike    2015-01-03 11:48:51 2015-01-06 22:19:27 82:30:36    10  825.10
Mike    2015-01-06 21:19:40 2015-01-06 22:00:00 00:40:20    10  6.72
```

My query is below

```
SELECT tt.id,ts.fname,tt.punch_in,tt.punch_out,
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,tt.punch_in,tt.punch_out)) as working_hours_new,ter.hourlyrate,
((SUBSTRING(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,tt.punch_in,tt.punch_out)),1,2) + SUBSTRING(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,tt.punch_in,tt.punch_out)),4,2)/60 + SUBSTRING(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,tt.punch_in,tt.punch_out)),7,2)/3600) * ter.hourlyrate) as pay
from tbl_times as tt left join tbl_server as ts on ts.serverid = tt.user_id left join tbl_employee_rates as ter on ter.userid=tt.user_id 
where ts.locationid = ? and ts.active = 1 and ter.stauts = 1 and date(punch_in) >=  ? and date(punch_out) <= ?
```

If this is not an easy way to do, should I do it in PHP... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try: (assuming mysql)

```
((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tt.punch_out) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tt.punch_in)) / 3600) * ter.hourlyrate AS salary
```

Answer (score 0):

Each programming language or a system is designed to do a certain amount of activities in a proper manner meanwhile not so much for other activities.

SQL is [designed to handle a set of certain activities](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171024/never-do-in-code-what-you-can-get-the-sql-server-to-do-well-for-you-is-this#answer-171042).

If your task is a subset of that set then you should complete your task by using SQL, unless you can specifically find a programming language or a system that is *designed to do it in a more proper way*.

In your case you're relying on **joins**, **filtering data**, etc, which SQL is speficially designed to handle -- so you should definitely be doing it with SQL.

Consider wrapping your codes in functions, packages or views to make your queries reusable for all systems.